# First Peter, 5:13 mentions "Mark, my son."

Tags: mark

Since Peter was married, and children were normal, and that he stayed with Mark's mother when he was in town, I think the chance is at least fair that this is a plain statement. Add to that Paul's reluctance to have such a young companion, especially one who would report to the Jerusalem church, and the argument strengthens. Is there evidence to refute this thought?

Comment: This sounds like speculation. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE, and thanks for taking the site tour. For more on what's on topic here and what this site is about, please see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites). As it is, it's not entirely clear to me what, exactly, you are asking.

Comment: Are you seriously asserting that 1. Paul was unfaithful with Mark's mother, and 2. that Mark was the illegitimate son of that union? Otherwise are you asking if Mark's mother was Peter's wife? If so  why would the Bible refer to her as Mark's mother rather than Peter's wife? Please reword your question.

Comment: More on John Mark: https://www.lds.org/ensign/1973/04/the-shepherds-flock?lang=eng#p48

Answer (score 2):

Well, the copts say: "St. marks parents, Aristopolos his father and Mary his mother"
Apostolic churches know a lot about genealogy of the NT figures, it helps a lot asking them.

From http://www.copticchurch.net/topics/synexarion/mark.html:

> St. Mark was a native of the North Africa county of Libya. He was born
>   in the city of Cyrene in Pentapolis, The western part of Libya, west
>   of the border of Egypt. St. Mark was born of Jewish parents three
>   years after the birth of our Lord and Savior, Jesus Christ. His
>   original name was John and his surname was Mark : "And when he {peter}
>   came to himself ....., he {Peter} came to the house of Mary the mother
>   of John, whose surname was Mark, where many gathered together praying"
>   (acts 12:11-12); and " Barnabas determined to take with them John,
>   whose surname was Mark" (acts 15:37); "And Barnabas and Saul returned
>   from Jerusalem, when they had fulfilled their ministry, and took with
>   them John, whose surname was Mark" (acts 12:25). St. marks parents,
>   **Aristopolos** ***his father*** and Mary his mother, migrated to Palestine
>   shortly after the birth of St. Mark because of the Berber attacks on
>   their town and property. They settled in Cana of Galilee not far form
>   Jerusalem **A few years later St. Mark's father died and Peter Simon {
>   St. Peter}, who was married to a relative of St. Mark's father took
>   care of St. Mark and considered him a son:** "The Church that is in
>   Babylon, elected together with you, salutes you and so does Marcus
>   {Mark} my son"; (1 Peter 5:13). Peter Simon saw to it that St. Mark
>   got a good education. St. Mark studied law and the classics.
>
> Church Traditions state that Mary, St. Mark's mother, was admirer of
>   Jesus Christ and followed Him everywhere and that St. Mark was one of
>   the attendants who served at the feast in Cana of Galilee at which
>   Jesus Christ turned the waster into wine: "And the third day there was
>   a marriage in Cana of Galilee ... and both Jesus and was called and
>   his disciples, to the marriage .. when the ruler of the feast had
>   tasted the water that was made wine, ... This was the first miracle
>   Jesus did ..." (John 2:1-11)

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you quoted some more from that link, including that Mark was Peter's relative and Peter assumed some parental responsibility for him, according to the source. Unfortunately, the link gives no historical evidence.

Comment: If Peter was a fisherman from Galilee, and Mark was his relative (by marriage) from Cyrene ... I conclude that your answer means "adopted son" or "step son" in our current usage.  Do I understand you correctly?